# How do I find the android SDK tools version from shell

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools, fastboot

I would like to get the version of the installed SDK on the computer from a shell command.

Some tools like adb and fastboot have an option to print their version, like `adb version`, `fastboot --version`, so I was expecting `android version` or similar, but there is none.

I don't want to launch any user interface, **shell only**.

Thanks

Comment: The `android` command is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open a command-prompt/terminal/console
2. Change directory to where you installed the the android sdk + tools + bin folder
3. then execute, `sdkmanager` with the `--list` command

Then you will get a a few lists (Installed packages, Available Packages, and Available Updates).

An osx command example :

```
[~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin] $ ./sdkmanager --list
```

As for `fastboot --version` and `adb --version`,  both of these commands tell you what version of the executable you are running on your machine and have nothing to do with what sdks are on the machine.  This is helpful in case you find a bug and wish to report an issue you find with those tools.

Comment: Thanks. Little bit less clutter:

`[~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin] $ ./sdkmanager --list | grep tool`

Comment: So which tells me the actual version of fastboot and adb that will run when I execute them? Can I assume its the latest version of platform-tools  from the list printed by `sdkmanager --list`?

Comment: You would have to see if there is an entry in the available update section for that information